# Vite JS merge output sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, vite, rollup, source-maps

We're using a [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for a project.
Works great and creates multiple chunks when building.

Recently i enabled sourcemaps and every chunk gets its individual `.map` file.

However, i'd like to have multiple chunks and just *one* combined/ merged sourcemap file that covers all chunks.

I couldn't find anything related within the vite/ rollup documentation.